# Don't show "Display Name" at sending e-mail

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, smtp

I send mail from my site (.NET Framework 2.0, IIS 7) as

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@email.com", "Name Name");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to@email.com", "");
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to);
mm.Subject = subject;
mm.Body = body;
using ( mm )
{
    if (attach != null)
        mm.Attachments.Add(attach);
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailPort))
        smtp.Port = int.Parse(mailPort);
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, pass);
    smtp.Send(mm);
}
```

But there is no Display Name ("Name Name") at getting letter, only e-mail.

Do you have any idea of what could cause this issue?

I'm sure, the email client isn't ignoring the display name! Client is Outlook.

When application transfer object `mm` to the server, property `From` is `{"Name Name" <from@email.com>}`. Why does server remove name?

Comment: Are you sure the email client isn't just ignoring the `display name`?

Comment: Code works for me, I'm afraid. DisplayName shows up just fine in Outlook.

Answer (score 4):

I've had trouble with this issue as well, but found that MailAddress also takes a third encoding argument.  So instead of using:

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@email.com", "Name Name");
```

Try some of these guys:

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@email.com", "Name Name", Encoding.ASCII);
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@email.com", "Name Name", Encoding.UTF8);
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@email.com", "Name Name", Encoding.Unicode);
```

This list is not limiting, there are other encoding options you can use.  I use gmail and after enabling the access for [Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en), it works for all of these after using the SmtpClient.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I tested it with gmail receiving address and by just using ```Encoding.UTF8``` as the third parameter, the display name worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seems that providing the credentials caused the server to use those for the 'from' name.

I had to comment out:

```
//client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// SMTP服务发送邮件
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mailSubjct">邮件主题</param>
    /// <param name="mailBody">邮件内容(html)</param>
    /// <param name="mailFrom">发件地址</param>
    /// <param name="mailAddress">收件地址</param>
    /// <param name="hostIp">SMTP主机IP</param>
    /// <param name="username">SMTP用户名</param>
    /// <param name="password">SMTP密码</param>
    /// <param name="ssl">是否启用SSL方式</param>
    /// <param name="port">SMTP端口</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string SendMail(string mailSubjct, string mailBody, string mailFrom, List<string> mailAddress, string hostIp, string username, string password, bool ssl, int port)
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
            mm.Subject = mailSubjct;
            mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.Body = mailBody;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mm.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, Const.SYS_NAME, Encoding.UTF8);

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");

            for (int i = 0; i < mailAddress.Count; i++)
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(mailAddress[i]))
                {
                    mm.To.Add(mailAddress[i]);
                }
            }
            if (mm.To.Count == 0)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

            sc.EnableSsl = ssl;
            sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            sc.Credentials = nc;
            sc.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            sc.Host = hostIp;
            sc.Port = port;
            sc.Send(mm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
        return error;
    }
```

---

i am chinese, and my english is poor. haha....

int this row,second parameter : "mm.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, Const.SYS_NAME, Encoding.UTF8);"

DisplayName : "Const.SYS_NAME ", i think this is you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the DisplayName property of the MailAddress object to set the regular name, instead of just using the email address.

```
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("thedude@lebowski.net");
fromAddress.DisplayName = "The Dude";
```

Comment: MailAddress.DisplayName is only a getter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.displayname.aspx. You can set in the MailAddress overload that the OP uses.